# Add code in specific point with Roslyn

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn, vspackage

Is there a way to add a code in a specific point with Roslyn (also without roslyn)? This is my problem: I develop a vspackage that add a command in the context menu (in CODE WINDOW). When I right click and I select this command it should add some code in that point.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Some time has passed since you asked for help, but I'm curious; did my solution below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

- receive the current text window of visual studio
- get the position in the textbuffer (clicking the right mouse button will set the caret position)
- insert your text

First things first; receive the text view:

```
public static IWpfTextView GetCurrentTextView(Package package)
{
    try
    {
        var serviceProvider = package as IServiceProvider;
        IVsTextManager textManager = (IVsTextManager)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));

        IVsTextView textView;
        textManager.GetActiveView(1, null, out textView);

        IComponentModel componentModel = (IComponentModel)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        var factoryService = componentModel.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();

        return factoryService.GetWpfTextView(textView);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Get the caret position from that and insert your text:

```
IWpfTextView textView = GetCurrentTextView(package);
SnapshotPoint caretPosition = textView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
textView.TextBuffer.Insert(caretPosition, "HELLO WORLD");
```

Don't forget to add error handling.